# Reading Semi Structured Emails into R

Tags: r, email

I have a list of emails saved as text files. My eventual goal is to get the emails into a DF in R, with the email fields like date , time , body, address as the column titles. The emails are all formatted the same way ( i think, may be a few rogues). Below is a sample.

Date, 9/5/2014,Time,2:34:54 PM,Name, Bert John,Email, Jane Doe@gmail com,pageName, Home,Form_Comments, This is a generic email with the content removed for privacy ,Identity, Generic,****

All the the emails were read into a word document, and I wrote a macro to put them in a comma separated style. The **** is there to mark the end of an email. I am not sure where to start to script R to read this word document, and create the table I am looking for. Most of my R experience is in analysis not data step programming. I understand the word document may need to be edited as well to read into R. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took your datafile, copied it to itself once, and replaced ",****" with CR using a text editor, saved it to disk as a .txt file and then read it:

```
df = read.csv("c:\\users\\n\\box sync\\test.txt", header = FALSE)
```

The output is

```
    V1        V2   V3         V4   V5    V6                  V7       V8    V9
1 Date  9/5/2014 Time 2:34:54 PM Name Email  Jane Doe@gmail com pageName  Home
2 Date  9/5/2014 Time 2:34:54 PM Name Email  Jane Doe@gmail com pageName  Home
            V10                                                            V11
1 Form_Comments  This is a generic email with the content removed for privacy 
2 Form_Comments  This is a generic email with the content removed for privacy 
       V12      V13
1 Identity  Generic
2 Identity  Generic
```

Comment: Thanks, just need to add some column titles and it looks good to go